# inserting edited pdf

Tags: pdftex

I am including an edited pdf into the latex by `\includegraphics[height=2.3in]{fig.pdf}`. The figure is inserted exactly as per my requirement. But i couldn't find the editings (inserted square, rectangle) in my latex, whereas I could find them if i open the image in preview
[image: fig.pdf].
 The image has been edited in mac preview. The oval and rectangle, which is found in this image, is missing when i insert the image to my latex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you added the rectangle and the circle via `preview.app`?
In that case they are annotations which are added on a separate layer and can easily be edited. This annotation layer will normally not be displayed, if you print the file or `\includegraphics{...}`.

What you need to do is "flatten" the `pdf`-file.
Using `preview.app` you can achieve this in two different ways:

1. Print dialog: just activate the option to include annotations and generate a new pdf via the menu in the left bottom corner.
2. Use the `Export as PDF…` option from the `File` menu. This is actually the easier way.

To check, that the annotations are really flattened, just open the new file. If you can't edit them anymore, everything went right. Of course you should keep a copy of the original file, because you cannot change the annotations anymore! (At least not with `preview.app`…)

Screenshots (german, but that should not really matter…):

[image]

[image]